# TFS CommitCheckin event is not firing

Tags: tfs

I am using Visual Studio TFS 2010 and want to develop an notification application. I tried **CommitCheckin** event handler exposed by **VersionControlServer** class. But the event is not firing. I use it to notify user whenever a checkin is done.

Comment: Some code maybe? Users could just create an alert, if they want to get notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most of the `VersionControlServer` class events are only fired when changes happen in process. What you are trying to do is to find out when change happened in another process. This functionality is not documented well, but should be doable:
[`PendingChangesChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.pendingchangeschanged.aspx) event is fired cross process.

I believe you need to initialize [`NotificationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.notificationmanager.aspx) in your process in order to receive notifications.

Comment: That's generally correct around PendingChangesChanged.  What's actually going on here - when you change the Pending Changes list in one client, it notifies the other clients using IPC that they should then refresh their pending changes, and they will also fire the appropriate events.  There are some wrinkles - for example, the TFS plug-in For Eclipse 2010 does not participate in the IPC, and you cannot tell if changes were undone or if a check-in occurred (just that the pending changes are gone.)